# The difference between `android:breadCrumbShortTitle` and `android:breadCrumbTitle`

Tags: android

While I'm reading the [android.R.attr](http://android.xsoftlab.net/reference/android/R.attr.html) documentation, I found the `breadCrumbTitle` and `breadCrumbShortTitle`. What is the usage of these 2 attributes? Does android provide a breadCrumb view in platform base and if so what is it looks like? Why did these 2 attribute exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're used in the [`PreferenceActivity`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.java):

```
sa.peekValue(com.android.internal.R.styleable.PreferenceHeader_breadCrumbTitle);
```

Specifically, they're set on `PreferenceActivity.Header` instances that are being pulled out of a `preference_headers` XML file:

```
tv = sa.peekValue(com.android.internal.R.styleable.PreferenceHeader_breadCrumbTitle);
if (tv != null && tv.type == TypedValue.TYPE_STRING) {
    if (tv.resourceId != 0) {
        header.breadCrumbTitleRes = tv.resourceId;
    } else {
        header.breadCrumbTitle = tv.string;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, there's very little documentation about what this feature does - where it shows up, how it's used on different API levels, etc. The [official Settings guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings) doesn't even mention them.

There's also a concept of [`FragmentBreadCrumbs`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentBreadCrumbs) but that doesn't appear to use this attribute (and is even more sparsely documented!).

**Edit**: Looking further, it turns out that these features work in tandem! If the preference headers have breadcrumbs set, then those breadcrumbs are used in conjunction with the `FragmentBreadCrumbs` widget, assuming one exists with the id `android.R.id.title`, *and* we're in a multi-pane preferences page:

```
/**
 * Change the base title of the bread crumbs for the current preferences.
 * This will normally be called for you.  See
 * {@link android.app.FragmentBreadCrumbs} for more information.
 */
public void showBreadCrumbs(CharSequence title, CharSequence shortTitle) {
    if (mFragmentBreadCrumbs == null) {
        View crumbs = findViewById(android.R.id.title);
        // For screens with a different kind of title, don't create breadcrumbs.
        try {
            mFragmentBreadCrumbs = (FragmentBreadCrumbs)crumbs;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            setTitle(title);
            return;
        }
        if (mFragmentBreadCrumbs == null) {
            if (title != null) {
                setTitle(title);
            }
            return;
        }
        if (mSinglePane) {
            mFragmentBreadCrumbs.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            // Hide the breadcrumb section completely for single-pane
            View bcSection = findViewById(com.android.internal.R.id.breadcrumb_section);
            if (bcSection != null) bcSection.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            setTitle(title);
        }
        mFragmentBreadCrumbs.setMaxVisible(2);
        mFragmentBreadCrumbs.setActivity(this);
    }
    if (mFragmentBreadCrumbs.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
        setTitle(title);
    } else {
        mFragmentBreadCrumbs.setTitle(title, shortTitle);
        mFragmentBreadCrumbs.setParentTitle(null, null, null);
    }
}
```